# как сделать volume, доступный с другого хоста?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Я создаю ранчер каталог, там можно указать путь к  volume только на хосте запуска, т.е. в самом каталоге видеть отказывается. Как можно передать volume? Может есть какой-то вариант вроде приватного registry для images?